# DOM accessing element JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

Given the following xml

```
<rss>
    <channel>
    ...
    <pubDate>20/30/2099</pubDate>
    ...
    <item>
        ...
        <pubDate>10/30/2099</pubDate>
        ...
    </item>
    ...
    <item>
        ...
        <pubDate>40/30/2099</pubDate>
        ...
    </item>
    ...
    </channel>
</rss>
```

how would I efficiently access `pudDate` in `channel` and `items` as array, as well as `pudDate` in that array.

Comment: which server-side language are you using?

Comment: @Sarfraz: it's actually client side javascript, specifically going to use in firefox extension.

Comment: Figured out that can get items collection with 

var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

However, can't believe I have to iterate through each element and check the tag name...

Comment: or I have to rely on the order of the elements and use indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use xpath (as long as you don't need it for IE), using *document.evaluate*. Here's the function I use for it:

```
 function getFromXPath(expression,rootEl){
   rootEl = rootEl || docbody;
   var ret = [] 
             ,xresult = document.evaluate(expression, rootEl, null,
                         XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null)
             ,result = xresult.iterateNext();
   while (result) {
     ret[ret.length]= result;
     result = xresult.iterateNext();
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Where in your case `expression` could be something like `"//channel/pubdate|channel/item/pubdate"` (for all `pubdates` in the tree) or `"//chanel/items"` (for all `item` elements in the tree), and `rootEl` being the (xml) document root.

This function returns an array containing the elements you requested by xpath-expression.